# Reset Date standard for ICP (Indice Camara Promedio) trade

Tags: interest-rates, interest-rate-swap

What is the Reset Date standard for ICP (Indice Camara Promedio) trade? Trade Currencies are USD v/s CLP. Please provide the ISDA link if there are any amendments to ISDA standards.